# USB keyboard is not working in Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)

Tags: 13.04

My old USB keyboard isn't working with Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) server. I've searched and googled, but I can't find a fix.

I can't plug an old keyboard with [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) connection in it. But my USB mouse is working. I'm using [Lenevo ThinkCentre M72e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkCentre_M_Series#M72e).

Comment: Have you perhaps tried a different USB port?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem which didn't allow me to do a 13.10 server install. I believe that [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1238194) may be related to your problem

The fix given in the bug report, you will need some kind of keyboard or input device, suggests enable the saucy-proposed repository, open

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now add this to the end of the file

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

Now now install

```
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

and update `initramfs`

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Finally reboot for the kernel changes to be applied

```
sudo reboot
```

This will install  `initramfs-tools` and `initramfs-tools-bin` version `0.103ubuntu1.1` and your keyboard should work.